# Extract CSS difference for theme-aware styles

Tags: css, webpack, sass

I have a project where the CSS is generated from Sass via webpack.
I do have a few Sass variables which are used for theming: $color-primary, $color-bg, ...

As I want to create a light and dark theme I have to compile it to two CSS files, which isn't really a problem.

The problem is that both `app-light.css` and `app-dark.css` have most of their styles in common as they are not theme-aware.

What I want is **extract all selectors and properties which are theme-aware** and save it into `app-dark.css`, so it only contains data which is relevant for the theme.

Example diff (app-light.css and app-dark.css side-by-side):
[image]

I need to find a tool or a way on how to create an `app-dark.css` which would generate the following for the shown diff:

`h1 { color:#fff; }`

That's it, because that's the only theme-aware property and selector.

Comment: Take a look at this good example of how a **dark/light theme** [should be done](https://codepen.io/ananyaneogi/pen/zXZyMP).
You do not need two separate files.

Comment: @GrzegorzT. My project is using Sass variables (as stated in the question) and not CSS variables.

Comment: There is a tool that can do that. It is called `diff` on Linux and derivates :).

Answer (score 1):

You can make a clean split with the help of global Sass variables and a mixin.

I'm guessing your starting point is two separate files and probably some Sass partials that are imported and compiled in these two files.

First chose your champions in each of the files, like this:

```
/* In app-light.scss */
$globalTheme: light !global;

/* In app-dark.scss */
$globalTheme: dark !global;
```

Then create a @mixin that returns the content only if your global variable AND the mixin argument is either *light* or *dark*, like this:

```
/* @mixin onlyInTheme() */
@mixin onlyInTheme($theme: null) {
    @if (global-variable-exists(globalTheme)) {
        @if ($theme == light and $globalTheme == light) {
            @content;
        }
        @if ($device == dark and $globalTheme == dark) {
            @content;
        }
    } @else {
        @warn "Global $appTheme variable does not seem to exist. No mixin for you!";
    }
}
```

Now you can write separate rules for each theme, and they will only be compiled to the corresponding file. Here's an example:

```
h1 {
    font-weight: 400; 
    margin: 0 0 3rem;
    line-height: 1.3;

    @include onlyInTheme(light) {
        color: #000;
    }

    @include onlyInTheme(dark) {
        color: #fff;
    }
}
```

This should give you the diff you want between the two files.