# split resulting css code from scss source into multiple css files based on used sass mixin

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I need to write a html5 template with different "flavors" or color-variants.

I would like to have one scss file to work on but several css files to be rendered.

Lets say my scss entry point is app.scss

IMHO the ideal approach would be something like:

```
$flavors: (
    flavor-a: (
        background: white
    ),
    flavor-b: (
        background: grey
    )
);

@mixin flavor($name) {
    /* parser-rule-start */
    @content;
    /* parser-rule-end */
}

html {
    /* regular rule - valid for all flavors => goes to app.css */
    font-family: sans-serif;
    @each $name, $options in $flavors {
        @include flavor($name) {
            /* flavor-rule => goes to flavor-a.css / flavor-b.css */
            background: map-get($options, 'background');
        }
    }
}
```

so i end up with

- app.css
- flavor-a.css
- flavor-b.css

I had that requirement before and solved it with multiple entry files, that call mixins for colorization and so on.

But i dont like that approach because after i code the scss for a new component, i would need to move chunks of lines from the structure file to the flavor-mixin, that is called in the flavor-*.scss entry files.

ATM my build looks like (gulp):

```js
/**
 * compile/concat scss
 */
gulp.task('css', function () {

    const sassOptions = {
        outputStyle: "compressed",
        errorLogToConsole: true
    };

    const autoprefixerOptions = {
        browsersList: [
            "last 2 versions",
            "ie >= 11"
        ]
    };

    return gulp
        .src("src/scss/*.scss")
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass(sassOptions).on('error', makeErrorLogger('css')))
        .pipe(autoprefixer(autoprefixerOptions))
//      .pipe(splitFlavors()) <- the point i would need some magic
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("public/static/css"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream({match: '**/*.css'}));
});
```

Does someone know a gulp plugin for that purpose or do i have to code it myself?

Comment: Just trying to understand the question a bit better - can you explain the problem with the "multiple entry files" solution? I don't get why that wouldn't solve your issue.

Comment: Is it an option to have two entry points instead? If `flavor-a.scss` and `flavor-b.scss` were to import the common partial `_app.scss`, you could split the output with a mixin. See my answer to this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58284016/extract-css-difference-for-theme-aware-styles/58286250

Comment: @wiiiiilllllll The multiple entry points do solve the issue basically, so its just about how to make it easier to maintain. When using multiple entry point files i need to extract all flavor-specific rules (so i end up with 2 includes per component) to a separat include/mixin. Using the split like explained above would make that easier. I could simply define the rules, that are different from flavor to flavor in a include-block and loop through some flavors-array...

Comment: @Trollsyn Yes, it is an option - one that i used before - but i am asking for a way i consider easer to write/maintain.

Comment: Have you looked at @Trollsyn 's answer? It looks like it would do what you want (and looks really cool, I will use this in future - kudos Trollsyn!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE 3**

another adoption for replacement

```js
let newSelector = selector.replace(/\s?\:\:flavor\-([^\s]+)/g, "").trim();
```

**UPDATE 2**

the replacement in the selector of the css rule needs to be adopted

```js
let newSelector = selector.replace(/\s?\:\:flavor\-([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\s]+)/g, "").trim();
```

**UPDATE**

by using a modified selector rather than properties you can continue using nested rules inside a "for-flavor" block.

So adjust the mixin to look like:

```
@mixin for-flavor($name) {
  ::flavor-#{$name} & {
    @content;
  }
}
```

and the gulp task:

```js
const path = require("path");
const gulp = require("gulp");
const sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps");
const sass = require("gulp-sass");
const autoprefixer = require("gulp-autoprefixer");
const through = require("through2");
const postcss = require("gulp-postcss");

/**
 * compile/concat scss
 */
gulp.task('css', function () {

    const sassOptions = {
        outputStyle: "compressed",
        errorLogToConsole: true
    };

    const autoprefixerOptions = {
        browsersList: [
            "last 2 versions",
            "ie >= 11"
        ]
    };

    function addFlavorFiles() {
        return through.obj(function(file, encoding, callback) {
            /* @var file File */
            let content = file.contents.toString();
            let names = [];
            let matches = content.match(/\:\:flavor\-([^\s\{]+)/g);
            if (matches) {
                names = matches.map(match => match.replace(/\:\:flavor\-/, '').trim());
                // unique
                names = names.filter((el, index, arr) => {
                    return index === arr.indexOf(el);
                });
            }
            names.forEach(name => {
                let newFile = file.clone();
                newFile.contents = Buffer.concat([Buffer.from(`/*!flavor:${name}*/\n`, encoding), file.contents]);
                let filePath = path.parse(file.path);
                newFile.path = path.join(filePath.dir, `flavor-${name + filePath.ext}`);
                this.push(newFile);
            });
            callback(null, file);
        })
    }

    function filterFlavors(css, opts) {
        let flavor = null;
        if (css.nodes[0].type === "comment" && css.nodes[0].text.indexOf('!flavor:') === 0) {
            flavor = css.nodes[0].text.replace(/^\!flavor\:/, "").trim();
        }
        css.walkRules(rule => {
            let selector = rule.selector;
            if (/^\:\:flavor\-/.test(selector)) {
                // flavor rule
                if (flavor === null) {
                    // general file, all flavor rules must go...
                    rule.remove();
                } else {
                    let matches = selector.match(/\:\:flavor\-([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/);
                    let currentFlavor = matches[1];
                    if (flavor !== currentFlavor) {
                        // wrong flavor
                        rule.remove();
                    } else {
                        // keep rule but adjust selector
                        let newSelector = selector.replace(/^\:\:flavor\-([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/, "").trim();
                        rule.selector = newSelector;
                    }
                }
            } else if(flavor !== null) {
                // general rule but flavor file, so remove the rule
                rule.remove();
            }
        });
        css.walkRules(rule => {
            if (!rule.nodes || rule.nodes.length === 0) {
                rule.remove();
            }
        });
        css.walkAtRules(atRule => {
            if (!atRule.nodes  || atRule.nodes.length === 0) {
                atRule.remove();
            }
        });
        // optional: delete all font-face definitions from flavor file
        if (flavor !== null) {
            css.walkAtRules(atRule => {
                if (atRule.name === "font-face") {
                    atRule.remove();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    return gulp
        .src("src/scss/*.scss")
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass(sassOptions).on('error', makeErrorLogger('css')))
        .pipe(addFlavorFiles())
        .pipe(autoprefixer(autoprefixerOptions))
        .pipe(postcss([filterFlavors]))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("public/static/css"))
});
```

---

**ORIGINAL POST**

I managed to solve it like i intended to

Use a sass mixin, that adds rules for parsing:

```
@mixin for-flavor($name) {
  -flavor-start: unquote($name);
  @content;
  -flavor-end: unquote($name);
}
```

use it in for your css declarations

```
// you get the idea...
$flavors: (
  "lightblue": (
    background: lightblue,
  ),
  "pink": (
    background: pink,
  ),
  "dark": (
    background: black
  ),
);

#page-header {
  background: black;
  @each $name, $options in $flavors {
    @if map_has_key($options, 'background') {
      @include for-flavor($name) {
        background: map_get($options, 'background');
      }
    }
  }
  @include for-flavor("lightblue") {
    /* special rule for specific flavor */
    color: black;
  }
}
```

gulp

```js
const path = require("path");
const gulp = require("gulp");
const sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps");
const sass = require("gulp-sass");
const autoprefixer = require("gulp-autoprefixer");
const through = require("through2");
const postcss = require("gulp-postcss");

/**
 * compile/concat scss
 */
gulp.task('css', function () {

    const sassOptions = {
        outputStyle: "compressed",
        errorLogToConsole: true
    };

    const autoprefixerOptions = {
        browsersList: [
            "last 2 versions",
            "ie >= 11"
        ]
    };

    function addFlavorFiles() {
        return through.obj(function(file, encoding, callback) {
            /* @var file File */
            let content = file.contents.toString();
            let names = [];
            let matches = content.match(/\-flavor\-start\:([^\;]+)/g);
            if (matches) {
                names = matches.map(match => match.replace(/\-flavor\-start\:/, '').trim());
            }
            names.forEach(name => {
                let newFile = file.clone();
                newFile.contents = Buffer.concat([Buffer.from(`/*!flavor:${name}*/\n`, encoding), file.contents]);
                let filePath = path.parse(file.path);
                newFile.path = path.join(filePath.dir, `flavor-${name + filePath.ext}`);
                this.push(newFile);
            });
            callback(null, file);
        })
    }

    function filterFlavors(css, opts) {
        let flavor = null;
        if (css.nodes[0].type === "comment" && css.nodes[0].text.indexOf('!flavor:') === 0) {
            flavor = css.nodes[0].text.replace(/^\!flavor\:/, "").trim();
        }
        let inFlavorBlock = "";
        css.walkDecls(decl => {
            let prop = decl.prop;
            let isControlProp = false;
            let value = decl.value.trim();
            if (prop === "-flavor-end") {
                inFlavorBlock = "";
                isControlProp = true;
            } else if (prop === "-flavor-start") {
                inFlavorBlock = value;
                isControlProp = true;
            }
            let isValid = ((inFlavorBlock === "" && flavor === null) || inFlavorBlock === flavor);
            if (isValid === false || isControlProp) {
                decl.remove();
            }
        });
        css.walkRules(rule => {
            if (!rule.nodes || rule.nodes.length === 0) {
                rule.remove();
            }
        });
        css.walkAtRules(atRule => {
            if (!atRule.nodes  || atRule.nodes.length === 0) {
                atRule.remove();
            }
        });
    }

    return gulp
        .src("src/scss/*.scss")
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass(sassOptions))
        .pipe(addFlavorFiles())
        .pipe(autoprefixer(autoprefixerOptions))
        .pipe(postcss([filterFlavors]))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("public/static/css"))
});
```

The only remaining problem is, that the sourcemaps are not filtered...